# Safer conditional compilation?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

In an MSVC C++ program I have a part of code which I want to enable or disable depending on a preprocessor definition

```
// 1.h
#ifdef MYOPTION
//...
#endif
```

But I find that it is quite dangerous when it is used in a .h file included in more than one compilation unit, as I can easily get inconsistent headers (I don't want to define MYOPTION globally as it would require a complete recompilation each time I change it):

```
// 1.cpp
#define MYOPTION
#include "1.h"

// 2.cpp
#include "1.h"
```

Of course, it is much more complicated than this simplified example due to the chained header inclusion.

Is there a way to avoid such inconsistency, e.g. have a compile-time error without too much effort?

I thought of doing `#define MYOPTION 0` or `1`, but then I would have to write something like

```
#if MYOPTION == 1
//...
#elif !defined(MYOPTION)
#error ...
#endif
```

which looks too complicated... Maybe there is a better option?

Comment: You don't want to define `MYOPTION` globally, yet you want its existence to be globally consistent?  That sounds a little contradictory...!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I don't want it to be defined globally, but I want a compilation error in case of an error, such as in my `!defined` example. What exactly do you find contradictory?

Comment: @7vies: If something needs to be globally consistent, then the obvious place to define it is at a global level (either in a header file included by everything that relies on the definition, or on the command line).

Comment: Make two projects with the same code, one where it's globally defined and one where it's not?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: I know, but I don't want it to be defined globally as I said, because MSVC would recompile everything when a global macro is changed.

Comment: @UncleBens: There are more than one options, should I create 2^N projects? ;)

Comment: You probably want to create a separate *configuration*, not project. See my answer.

Comment: @Marlon: 2^N configurations is no better...

Comment: If you don't specify 2^n options, how will the compiler differentiate 2^n options? ;)

Comment: @Marlon: by recompiling only the changed (directly or through inclusion) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this: have 1.h define a dummy section in the obj with different options. This way, if MYOPTION is ever used inconsistently, the linker will issue a warning.

1.h:

```
#ifdef MYOPTION
#pragma section("MYOPTION_GUARD",write)
#else
#pragma section("MYOPTION_GUARD",read)
#endif

namespace { __declspec(allocate("MYOPTION_GUARD")) int MYOPTION_guard; }
```

Compiling with MYOPTION defined in a.cpp but not in b.cpp yields this linker warning (using VC 2008):

```
b.obj : warning LNK4078: multiple 'MYOPTION_GUARD' sections found with different attributes (40300040)
```

A consistent definition yields no linker warnings at all.

Comment: Thanks! I've looked into the different pragmas, but didn't think of this option, looks promising...

Answer (score 1):

I think you've listed most solution yourself, basically. I would use the last solution, but perhaps in a slightly different form:

```
#ifndef MYOPTION
#error ...
#endif

...

#if MYOPTION == 1
//...
#endif
```

Because often this #if MYOPTION == 1 will appear more than once in each file. It's also clearer that MYOPTION is a requisite for that file.

You say it "looks too complicated", but I'm afraid there's probably no solution that's less "complicated" than this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually need to use the defines, better is to define them via the compiler command line than `#define` in your source files. Then your `configure` script/makefile/build process sets the define once and you're guaranteed that it will agree properly across all source files.

Comment: I have mentioned this in the question: *I don't want to define MYOPTION globally as it would require a complete recompilation* (each time I change it)

Comment: @7vies: That problem is somewhat specific to Visual Studio (which you did mention briefly).  Many make systems don't recompile all targets just because the makefile changed (and that causes other problems).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you want is to create a separate configuration.

You can go to **Build -> Configuration Manager** and create a new configuration (separate from DEBUG, RELEASE). Creating a new configuration will allow you to define preprocessor symbols specific to that configuration.

For example, with a new configuration titled "MyOption 1" you could add the preprocessor definition `MYOPTION = 1`. The same thing goes with MYOPTION = 2, 3, ...

Each configuration has to be built separately.
DEBUG and RELEASE are examples of separate configurations; DEBUG defines `_DEBUG` and RELEASE defines `NDEBUG`